# PHP Include based on date

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to change includes based on a specific date. Would something like this work:

```
if (date('m/d/Y') < date('m/d/Y', strtotime("01/10/2011"))) {
    //Display something
}
else if (date ('m/d/Y') >= date('m/d/Y', strtotime("01/10/2011")) && date ('m/d/Y') <= date("m/d/Y', strtotime("05/10/2011"))           
    // Display something else
else {
    //Display something different
}
```

If i am understanding the strtotime function correctly, I would figure it would work. But I am not so sure I am understanding it correctly. Let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`date` returns a string like `2011-01-26`, which you can't compare to another string like `2011-02-23` with any useful result. You need to compare timestamps as produced by `strtotime` or `time`:

```
if (time() /* (now) */ < strtotime('2011-01-26')) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

[`date`](http://php.net/date) returns a string, when you compare the return values of that function, you are comparing strings. String comparison of dates in the 'm/d/Y' format does not compare the dates the way you're expecting it to (however, if you used the [standard format](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/iso-date) it would).

I suggest you compare the timestamps directly:

```
if (time() < strtotime('2011-01-01')) { /* include something */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should compare timestamps (what `strtotime` and `time` return) instead of strings (what `date` returns).

Like this:

```
if (time() < strtotime('01/10/2011')) {
    //Display something
}
else if (time() >= strtotime('01/10/2011') && time() <= strtotime('05/10/2011'))
    // Display something else
else {
    //Display something different
}
```

**Edit**: also, use single quotes when you don't need php to parse them. They work slightly faster.

Comment: In scenarios like this, don't use the same function over and over again with the same parameters. Instead, store the value in a variable and use it. One reason is increased processing, the other reason (relevant here) is the values that `time()` are not the same for all 3 function calls.